# Trigger with conditions around value of "Related To"

Tags: trigger

This is technically my first "production" trigger and I've spent a lot of time on this so far.

Basic premise is that I have the task object and when the `Related To` (WhatId) is facing a particular record type (custom object `supplier__c`), I want to fill the `supplier__c` lookup field of that new task with the value in the `Related To` field. This will need to account for null values or other object types in the `Related To` field.

Please excuse all the sys debugs / comments. I added these for my own clarity.

```
// sets Supplier__c as = to WhatId when WhatId is a Supplier Type
trigger setTaskSupplier on Task (before insert, before update) {
    system.debug('----->>> TRIGGER START');
    // instantiate list:
    list<Task> objList = new list<Task>();
    // instantiate recordtype:
    Id devRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Task.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Payment Task').getRecordTypeId();
    system.debug('----->>> devrecordtypeid: ' + devRecordTypeId);

    //add task to list if meets criteria
    for(Task obj : trigger.new){
            if ( String.valueof(obj.WhatId).startsWith('a1m') && obj.RecordTypeId == devRecordTypeId ) { 
                objList.add(new Task(Id = obj.id));
            }

            //set update on tasks in list
            for (Task upd : objList){
            upd.Supplier__c = upd.WhatId;
            system.debug('----->>> TRIGGER updates task id: ' + upd.Id);
            }

            //perform update:
            update objList;
            system.debug('----->>> TRIGGER END');
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are indeed some problems with your code.

You don't need to instantiate a new list of task. You can update the current task record inside your loop because you are inside a before trigger. Any change applied to the records is saved to the database.

Also, you can detect the type of a record using his Id without needing to check the prefix of the Id with the `getSobjectType()` method

So your code will be highly simplified:

```
trigger setTaskSupplier on Task (before insert, before update) {
    Id devRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Task.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Payment Task').getRecordTypeId();

    for(Task obj : trigger.new){
        if(obj.WhatId != null){
            if (obj.WhatId.getSobjectType() == Schema.Supplier__c.SObjectType && obj.RecordTypeId == devRecordTypeId ) { 
                obj.Supplier__c = obj.WhatId;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also do a null check on WhatId first, or your code will throw an error if the Task has no WhatId specified (for example, a Task directly on a Contact).

Comment: Thanks @Roti ! Didn't think of that.

Comment: Np. Another thing for @gscott, you didn't specify if Supplier__c should get cleared out if the WhatId is not a Supplier__c record or not. If so, then in the else section of either of the two if statements, you will need to clear out the Supplier__c field. The ideal solution would be to add a flag for something like whatIdIsSupplier, or something like that, and then after the if statements, if whatIdIsSupplier is false, set obj.Supplier__c to null. This is only if you need to clear it out in that scenario.